# Good resources for 2.5D and rendering walls, floors, and sprites

Tags: graphics, 2.5d

I'm curious as to how games like [Prelude of the chambered](http://s3.amazonaws.com/ld48/index.html) handle graphics. If you play for a bit you will see what I mean. It made me wonder how it works. (it is open-source so you can get the source on [this page](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-21/?action=preview&uid=398)) I did find a few tutorials, but I couldn't understand some of it, though it did help with some things. However, I don't like using code that I don't understand. Does anyone know of any good tutorials for this kind of 2.5D? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the orginal 'Doom' source code? It uses a similar technique.

Comment: @Vaughan Isn't doom a ray caster? I don't think the game I linked is a ray caster. I don't know where I could get the code anyway. And I probably wouldn't understand it either.

Comment: It -is- a Raycaster, but it does achieve a similar effect to what you want. I added it as a comment simply because it might be something you'd like to look at. However, I've added an answer below that might help some more.

Comment: Great question +1 for helping clear this issue up

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for a list of resources.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I wrote it a long time ago :)

Comment: I know; but something (an edit or the Community user) bumped it to the front page. There's a decent question in there, but probably not as phrased and it wouldn't fit the existing answers :/

Comment: @JoshPetrie I had edited it because my grammar wasn't that good back then. I was just saying that I didn't really understand the format back then. I don't really mind it being closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/index.html

Best tutorial on raycasting i could find when i was researching the topic a couple years back. It's pure theory, no programming. Other than that i suggest you read about the Doom engine and the Build engine. Reading the source code is IMHO far too time consuming (it's pure C and ASM, plus plenty of irrelevant technology quirks) if you just want to understand raycasting. Reading ABOUT the engines however can give you ideas on how to solve advanced issues like doors (as funny as that sounds), check the wiki first.

Here's a great code review by Fabien Sanglard: 
 http://fabiensanglard.net/doomIphone/doomClassicRenderer.php

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very detailed tutorial: [Creating pseudo 3D games with HTML 5 canvas and raycasting](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-pseudo-3d-games-with-html-5-can-1/). The key search term is "pseudo 3d game."

[image] [image]

---

Also I posted the text of the tutorials [scgrn mentioned](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/37768/229). (I think I read these a long time ago. I remember the ASCII diagrams!)

- [PXDTUT7.TXT](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8K3pQANN)
- [PXDTUT8.TXT](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4MV3jR1y)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of (very) old tutorials on Wolfenstein-style raycasting written by Peroxide. Search for "pxdtut7.zip" and "pxdtut8.zip". The code is written in Pascal but the concepts are explained very well.

Comment: Links would be nice, otherwise searching for these files will most probably show Stack Exchange and other programming sites in future. That's what I found: http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/6287/ZipFileList.aspx , http://www.findthatzip.com/search-500950-fZIP/winrar-winzip-download-pxdtut8.zip.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the specifics, but I got a few ideas just by browsing through the source-code of the game @ https://github.com/skeeto/Prelude-of-the-Chambered/tree/master/src/com/mojang/escape

Maybe you can find some things there that will help you.

EDIT:
I noticed you had linked to the page, but I meant to specifically link to this file:
https://github.com/skeeto/Prelude-of-the-Chambered/blob/master/src/com/mojang/escape/gui/Bitmap3D.java

Comment: I've already seen that file but I don't get it! I just need an understandable resource which explains this. Thanks for trying though. And if you do find something please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently following the tutorial by Lode Vandevenne:
http://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html. Note that this is only part 1 (basic raycasting and textured walls). Part 2 (ceiling and floor textures) and 3 (sprites) can be found by clicking the link "Back to Index".

I think it's great. It contains everything I needed to make my own engine. The tutorial is based on C++, but the concepts are described so well that translation to any language is easy. I'm coding in Java myself.

(I'm doing the vector calculus it a little differently than Lode, however. I'm using 2-element arrays to represent vectors, and a class of static (void) methods to manipulate them, as is done in this more advanced 3D raytracing tutorial by Michael Birken: http://meatfighter.com/juggler/ (also brilliant))